# Display Database data in a blockquote

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the database data 3 columns in blockquote bootstrap 4 tag. Column length 10 with an extra column of an id(not null autoincrement). It shows blank line and a blank source line. No text. Any idea how to do this .? Thanks in advance

I did try something like (php, bootstrap and sql code)

```
    //database connection file
    <?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'achy', 'achy');
    if (!$dbc) {
       die('Databse Not Connected :' . mysqli_error());
     }

     //Select Database
     $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($dbc, "test");
     if (!$db_selected) {
      die ("Databse Not connected : " . mysqli_error());
     }
     ?>

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($resultCheck > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

            }
        }

        ?>  
//bootstrap tag  
    <blockquote class="blockquote">
      <p class="mb-0 lead"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer"><?php echo $row['name2']; ?> <cite title="Source Title"><?php echo $row['product']; ?></cite></footer>
    </blockquote>
```

just tried:

```
 <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($resultCheck > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) ?>

    <blockquote class="blockquote">
      <p class="mb-0 lead"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer"><?php echo $row['name2']; ?><cite title="Source Title"><?php echo $row['product']; ?></cite></footer>
    </blockquote>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE).....
```

Comment: Did you miss the `:` at the end of your `while` statement? Pretty sure it should be ` while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):` See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing that style of PHP, you need to use a colon after control structures, so `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>` would work

Comment: Thanks. still error though now Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ......

Comment: You're missing one or more closing braces then.

Comment: yes you are right... Thanks again 
if($resultCheck > 0) { 
This was the issue ..Problem solved yay !!